# How to hide non-generic method in generic interface if one inherits other

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have interfaces:

```
public interface IQueryContainerGenerator
    {
        QueryContainer Generate(object source);
    }

    public interface IQueryContainerGenerator<in T>: IQueryContainerGenerator where T: class
    {
        QueryContainer Generate(T source);
    }
```

I need to hide from IntelliSense method signature `QueryContainer Generate(object source)` if I operate with generic version of interface.

How I can implement it?

I have tried to use explicit interface implementation in class `CompositeQueryContainerGenerator<T>: IQueryContainerGenerator<T> where T: class` but it not solved problem:

```
public class CompositeQueryContainerGenerator<T>: IQueryContainerGenerator<T> where T: class
{
    QueryContainer IQueryContainerGenerator.Generate(object source)
    {
        // some logic
    }

    QueryContainer IQueryContainerGenerator<T>.Generate(T source)
    {
        return ((IQueryContainerGenerator)this).Generate(source);
    }
}
```

Perhaps the problem is not solved in principle if I use interface inheritance. 
If so, which approach is more preferable? Is the class implementation of both interfaces separately?

Comment: What *is* the problem? The compiler will pick the generic method over the non-generic one, as it's a better fit. Explicit implementation *does* hide* the non-generic method unless someone explicitly asks for it. The code posted here though ends up using the *non-generic* method instead of the generic one. Why hide it then?

Comment: The non-generic method should call the generic one, not the other way round. Eg `QueryContainer IQueryContainerGenerator.Generate(object source)=>Generate((T)source);`